# Error 979: not a GROUP BY expression

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Getting an error when trying to return the LAST contact date

```
SELECT CDC.pat_id, MAX(SOC.contact_date), 
FROM hb61.cdcsaar_patients CDC
JOIN clarity.social_hx SOC ON CDC.pat_id=SOC.pat_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN clarity.smoking_cess_hx CESS ON CDC.pat_id=CESS.pat_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN clarity.social_hx_alc_use ALC on CDC.pat_id=ALC.pat_id
GROUP BY SOC.contact_date
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the selected columns (in this case, *CDC.pat_id*) on the **GROUP BY** clause, instead of col you're applying the aggregation function.

```
SELECT
  CDC.pat_id,
  MAX(SOC.contact_date)
FROM
  hb61.cdcsaar_patients CDC
  JOIN clarity.social_hx SOC ON CDC.pat_id = SOC.pat_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN clarity.smoking_cess_hx CESS ON CDC.pat_id = CESS.pat_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN clarity.social_hx_alc_use ALC on CDC.pat_id = ALC.pat_id
GROUP BY
  CDC.pat_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put any columns that you're *not* applying an aggregate function to in the GROUP BY clause (in this case `CDC.pat_id`, rather than `SOC.contact_date`).